# How to get the Style.BackColor of a datagridview cell

Tags: datagridview, get, cell, background-color

Using VS2010 VB.NET, I have a datagridview (dgv) where I set the background color of cells according to a certain value. This particular cell does not store any information and therefore I can not use the data in that cell to determine the background color.

My current attempts are a complete failure and MSDN is only particular to "setting" and not "getting" the background color of a cell.

Code I've tried"

```
if dgvNotes.Rows(clickedCell.RowIndex).Cells(1).Style.BackColor.ToString = "Red" then

if dgvNotes.Rows(clickedCell.RowIndex).Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.Red then
```

I am not able to find much information on the topic as most of the posts on various coding sites focusses on "setting" the background color.

Is there any way that I can determine cell background color after the dgv was populated ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write in cell click event

```
// using vb.net
System.Drawing.Color c = dgvNotes.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Style.BackColor;

//using c#
System.Drawing.Color c = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply which was also the answer I was looking for !!. I adapted the code to be more VB friendly. `Dim CellBkColor As System.Drawing.Color = dgvNotes.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Style.BackColor
            MsgBox(CellBkColor.ToString)`

Answer (score 1):

In the click event

```
if dgvNotes.Rows(clickedCell.RowIndex).Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.Red then
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not working for me

I have this code for setting the cells color and other properties

```
    public static void SetDgvHeader(DataGridView dgv,DataGridView clonedgv,string tarih,string[] dgv_Headers)
    {
        dgv.Rows.Clear();
        dgv.ColumnCount = dgv_Headers.Length;
        dgv.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        int dayNbr = int.Parse(datenbr.txt);
        dgv.Rows.Add(dayNbr);
        for (int i = 0; i < dgv_Headers.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5)
            {
                dgv.Columns[i].Width = 20;
                dgv.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            }
            else
            {
                dgv.Columns[i].Width = 78;
                clonedgv.Columns[i].Width = 78;
            }
            dgv.Columns[i].HeaderText = dgv_Headers[i];
            dgv.Columns[i].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
            dgv.Columns[i].ReadOnly = true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dayNbr; ++i)
        {
            dgv.Rows[i].Height = 20;
            for (int a = 0; a < dgv_Headers.Length; ++a)
            {
                dgv.Rows[i].Cells[a].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
                dgv.Rows[i].Cells[a].Value = "";
           }
        }
        dgv.Height = (dayNbr* dgv.Rows[0].Height) + 25;
        dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

When I comment the line where I add the white color I get this

[image]

if i supress the comment slashes

I get this

[image]