# How to check if a DataGridView cell has a custom BackColor

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell, backcolor

I have a DataGridView loaded with data and some cells have been highlighted with a custom BackColor. I need to check if a cell is highlighted (i don't know the higlight color in advance) to execute some code. I am using the following code:

```
Color CellColor = MyDataGrid.Rows[r].Cells[c].Style.BackColor;
//if (CellColor != Color.FromArgb(0,0,0,0)) {
//if (CellColor != Color.FromName("0")) {
if (CellColor != MiGrid.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor) {
    // Do something
}
```

I asume the not highlighted cells have the DefaultCellStyle.BackColor but it doesn't work. Since the DefaultCellStyle.BackColor returns Color.FromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0) I also tried comparing to that but it still doesn't work. Can anyone show me how to check if the cell doesn't have a custom Backcolor?

Comment: Why not (re)check the condition which results in you setting the backcolor to whatever?

Comment: [Here's how to the get the cell backcolor.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844778/how-to-get-the-style-backcolor-of-a-datagridview-cell)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all the folks that tryied to help. Fortunatelly I found out the answer myself: a DataGridView cell's default Backcolor is `Color.Empty`. If you check the `Style.BackColor` property of the cell against `Color.Empty` you can identify if the cell has been assigned a custom background color.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not apparent what environment are you using. From the context I would say that it's a `Winforms` and default `DataGridView`.

Next, what do you mean by *highlighted*? I get a notion, that you're confusing a bit *selection* and *styling*. The question whether you are after selecting or styling of the cell is important.

Providing you're after styling, the *default* cell color in winforms is:

```
SystemColors.Window
```

Even in the case that the Windows environment would use customized colors, this should wokrk. You can query against that color or set it to the cells.

If you want to find out what cells are selected, that *might* get a bit complicated. First, you have to ensure what *mode* the selection is in. Typical are `CellSelect`, `RowHeaderSelect` or `FullRowSelect`. The aim and mode of selection would have to be clarified.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and my excuses for the lack of information in the question. Your assumptions are correct, i am working on a Winforms application and a default DataGridView. Also when i say highlighted i mean the cell has a BackColor asigned through code, different than the default color.

Comment: I tried comparing the cell's Style.BackColor to SystemColors.Window but it doesn't work since a default cell returns the following color: {Name=0, ARGB(0,0,0,0)} and SystemColors.Window corresponds to {Name=Window, ARGB(255,255,255,255)}.